# How can one integrate SVN and Git?

Tags: github

Now we're developing an [open source mobile analytics](http://dev.cobub.com) in company by using SVN. But now we open source the code in [**Github**](http://github.com/cobub/razor).

For the management, we must continue use SVN in office, so how can I get a script or something else to help me get all the changed code from the SVN repository and commit and push it to Github automatically? And that now Github has some old version codes, and our local svn's codes are latest. How can I sync the svn code to Github, from which revision?

Another problem is the Github's folder structures are different from svn's code folder's structures. I need sync some sub-folders together to Github. How can I deal with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [svn2git project](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) (version 2.0) appears to be what you need:

> As of svn2git 2.0 there is a new feature to pull in the latest changes from SVN into your git repository created with svn2git. This is a one way sync, but allows you to use svn2git as a mirroring tool for your SVN repositories

Comment: Thanks. I've just found that Git has git-svn after git 1.5.3. What the differences between them?

Comment: afaik git-svn is a git interface to svn repositories, and your question was about syncing the svn source to github